# Order by "count (columns not null)"

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by

I'm looking at a way to order the MySQL results by a count of the columns where the value is not null. Therefore,

```
[id] [1] [1] [0] [1] [1] = 4

[id] [0] [1] [1] [1] [0] = 3

[id] [0] [0] [0] [1] [1] = 2

[id] [1] [0] [0] [0] [0] = 1
```

In the above case I'm ignoring the ID column but in practice I wouldn't care. ID is always NOT NULL so adding it to count wouldn't change the results.

Anyone have any idea on this that doesn't involve doing a PHP parse on the result into a new array? I'm trying to keep the processing portion in the DB level.

Comment: Don't you miss difference between `0` and `NULL`?

Comment: @zerkms they didn't bother coming to my birthday party, so honestly, I don't miss those jerks.

Comment: @glowcoder: don't get your irony :-(

Comment: Well, edited out the grammatical error. It did say "Don't you miss 0 and null?" And I was saying no I don't miss those guys, they're jerks anyway. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY IF(`a` IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(`b` IS NULL, 0, 1) ... DESC
```

Where `a`, `b`, ... is the names of fields (yes, you need to enumerate them all manually)

PS: if you don't know the difference between `0` and `NULL` this:

```
ORDER BY `a` + `b` ... DESC
```

will be good enough for you

Comment: Yea the [0]'s were just because I was lazy.  But yea, excellent, this will work well.  Makes maintenance a pain but hopefully I won't be changing the schema too often (but I am doing RAD... so we'll see haha)