# Order by Column1 value if it is not null, otherwise use Column2 value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

In SQL, is there a way to combine `ORDER BY` and `IS NULL` so that I can order by the value in column 1 if it is not null; and if it is null, order by the value in another column?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055540/order-by-countcolumns-not-null][1] - here is answer to your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055540/order-by-countcolumns-not-null

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use case expression:

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN Column1
    ELSE Column2
END
```

Or the corresponding syntactic sugar:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(Column1, Column2)
```

The result will be like:

```
column1 | column2
--------|--------
      1 |    1258
      2 |    5972
   null |       3
      4 |    3698
      5 |    7524
```

Note that the datatype of the two columns must be comparable (the RDBMS defines the rules).

Comment: thanks you very much. I don't understand this sentence NULL: "values appear at the top when sorted ascending so for all NULL" can you explain a bit more?

Comment: NULL is smaller than any value when sorted ascending. If your data is `-1, 0, 1, NULL` ascending sorting result in `NULL, -1, 0, 1`.

Comment: this `ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN Column2
ELSE Column1
END` seems a bit more clear to me. do i _have_ to use the `END` statement?

Comment: Yes, the `END` ends the `CASE` statement.

Comment: You can control where NULLs go by using `ORDER BY ... NULLS LAST`

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
  ORDER BY COALESCE(fieldA, fieldB);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try with the following:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(firstField, secondField)
```

Comment: MySQL ISNULL returns 1/0, not the non-null column (did you mean IFNULL?).

Answer (score -2):

I dont have any Tables atm where I could test it, but this may work, at least it did without useable data:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY IF( table2.id, table1.id, table1.name )
```

Also I don't know how the order would look like if table2.id is null sometimes, seems very instable.

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL (definitely not for Postgres)