# Ordering by col1 but if null order by col2 in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

I am currently trying to do something like this with EF Core (fictional example):

-- Tables:

**Entity1**
*Id* |
*UserId* (nullable) |
*GroupId* (nullable) |

**Group**
*Id* | *UserId*

**User**
*Id* | *Name*

-- Sample Data:

**Entity1**

*Id | UserId | GroupId*

1 | null | 1

2 | 3 | null

3 | null | 2

**User**

*Id | Name*

1 | John

2 | Jimmy

3 | Jessica

**Group**

*Id | UserId *

1 | 1

2 | 2

The entity can either have a user or a group. Depending on which case, I want to sort for the user.name (if it has a user order directly for **entity.user.name** otherwise order by **entity.group.user.name**. When Ordering by user.name I want the results to be interleaved, so it would feel like, user is never null in Enitity1.

```
query.OrderBy(x => (x.User??x.Group.User).Name)
```

I wished this would order by the User.Name if an user exists on the entity and if not it would order by the group.name of the entity.

**Expected results**
I would expect that the Ids of *Entity1* would be ordered like 2,3,1 (--> Jessica, Jimmy, John)

I found this: [Order by Column1 if Column1 is not null, otherwise order by Column2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003413/order-by-column1-if-column1-is-not-null-otherwise-order-by-column2)

But I wasn't sure how to convert that to EF Core. I know I can do what I want when I do it with LINQ in memory, but I was wondering, if there is a chance to execute this OrderBy on the db.

Comment: To be clear - is this one sort or two? Do all of the non-null users come before the first group, or are users and groups interleaved? Maybe add some *sample data* and *expected results* to your question.

Comment: I edited the question, to make it more clear. I was expecting that it would be interleaved.